# How to get count by using UNION operator

Tags: oracle

i'm trying to get total count by using UNION operator but it gives wrong count.

```
select count(*) as companyRatings from (
select count(*) hrs from (
select distinct hrs from companyA
)
union           
select count(*) financehrs from (
select distinct finance_hrs from companyB
)
union           
select count(*) hrids from (
select regexp_substr(hr_id,'[^/]+',1,3) hrid from companyZ
)
union           
select count(*) cities from (
select regexp_substr(city,'[^/]+',1,3) city from companyY
)
);
```

individual query's working fine but total count not matching.

individual results here: 12 19 3 6
present total count: 31

Actual total count:40.
so there is any alternate solution without UNION operator?

Comment: BTW don't make a seperate table for each company.

Comment: Use union all instead of union and  select sum(hrs) instead of select count in the main query.

Comment: @PavelGatnar - For this to work, all table should have same type of column, which will not be possible as his third and forth tables are derived.

Comment: Are you sure your current result is 40? It should be 4, i.e. four counts. (And if two or more of the counts where equal, `UNION` would remove the duplicates and you'd get 3, 2 or 1 as a result. Your query simply counts how many different counts you get from the tables; four in your example.

Comment: @Utsav: This is wrong. A count is an integer, so `SUM` would add up these four integers. This has nothing to do with what columns are being counted.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: Yes i'm getting 4,some times it gives correct result but some time it gives wrong count.

Answer (score 1):

To add values you'd use `+`. `UNION` is to add data sets.

```
select
  (select count(distinct hrs) from companyA)
  +
  (select count(distinct finance_hrs) from companyB)
  +
  (select count(regexp_substr(hr_id,'[^/]+',1,3)) from companyZ)
  +
  (select count(regexp_substr(city,'[^/]+',1,3)) from companyY)
  as total
from dual;
```

But I agree with juergen d; you should not have separate tables per company in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for this precise comment. Are you saying that the individual queries return counts, but the plus sign fails to add them? This is not likely.

Comment: Yes.If there is any alternate solution?

Comment: If you have an Oracle version that fails on `+`, then install a bugfix. I have, however, never heard of such a flaw in Oracle and would be extremely surprised if that were the case. So you'd better check again.

Answer (score 0):

Edit. Updated query using `Sum`

```
select sum(cnt) as companyRatings from 
(
    select count(*) as cnt from (select distinct hrs from companyA)
    union all          
    select count(*) as cnt from (select distinct finance_hrs from companyB)
    union all        
    select count(*) as cnt from (select regexp_substr(hr_id,'[^/]+',1,3) hrid from companyZ)
    union all       
    select count(*) as cnt from (select regexp_substr(city,'[^/]+',1,3) city from companyY)
)
```

Previous answer:

Try this

```
SELECT (
        SELECT count(*) hrs
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT hrs
            FROM companyA
            )
        ) 
        + 
        (
        SELECT count(*) financehrs
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT finance_hrs
            FROM companyB
            )
        ) 
        +
        (
        SELECT count(*) hrids
        FROM (
            SELECT regexp_substr(hr_id, '[^/]+', 1, 3) hrid
            FROM companyZ
            )
        )
        + 
        (
        SELECT count(*) cities
        FROM (
            SELECT regexp_substr(city, '[^/]+', 1, 3) city
            FROM companyY
            )
        ) 
AS total_count
FROM dual
```

Comment: i tried this way first two queries results added but third and fourth queries result not adding.

Comment: Check the updated answer with `sum`. If not working, try using inner query first without the sum. I highly doubt that any of last 2 of your queries might be wrong